# Troubles doing span:hover

Tags: hover, visibility, show, html, visible

First of all sorry for my poor English :

Well I have this CSS

```
span.favoritos {position:absolute;left:550px;visibility:hidden;}
span.favtitle {position:absolute;top:-20px;left:450px;visibility:hidden;background: rgba(81,81,81, .9);color:#f2f2f2;padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;width:115px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;}
.favoritos a {display:block;
width:24px;
height:24px;
text-indent:-9999px;
background:url(img/sprite2.png) -21px -324px no-repeat;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px}
.favoritos a:hover {
background:url(img/sprite2.png) -21px -283px no-repeat;}
.favsave a {display:block;
width:24px;
height:24px;
text-indent:-9999px;
background:url(img/sprites.png) -121px -108px no-repeat;
border:1px #ececec solid;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;}
.content:hover span.favoritos {visibility:visible;}
.content:hover span.favdel {visibility:visible;}
.favoritos:hover span.favtitle {visibility:visible;}
```

And this HTML

```
 <div class="content">
        <span class="favtitle">Añadir a favoritos</span>
                        <span class="favoritos"><a title="Guardar en favoritos" href="#oferta-guardada">favoritos</a></span>
    </div>
```

But when I do hover on `<span class="favoritos"></span>` does not work, it doesn't show `<span class="favtitle">`

I have no idea why.

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: You must try using fire bug, with fire fox... will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

`span.favtitle` is not a descendant of `.favoritos:hover` as you are trying to address it in the last selector.

Comment: Thank you. But now, How can I do to show span.favtitle when I do hover on span.favoritos?

Comment: Alas, CSS does not support this kind of "reverse" relations, as it simply does not scale (requires traversing the entire DOM node subtree in certain situations.) You can do this using JS `mousemove`/`mouseout` listeners on `span.favoritos` and updating the `span.favtitle` class.